# Vertical alignment on editable UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uitextview, vertical-alignment

I want to set the vertical alignment on my `UITextView`. The text view is editable and scroll is disabled:

```swift
let textView = UITextView(frame: frame)
textView.backgroundColor = .clear
textView.attributedText = myAttributedString
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textView.isEditable = true
textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
textView.textContainerInset = .zero
self.addSubview(textView)
```

So, I would like to do something like :

```swift
textView.verticalAlignment = .center
```

I already tried subclassing the text view and adding an attribute like this:

```swift
class MyTextView: UITextView {
    public var verticalAlignment: UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment = .center {
        didSet {
            let topCorrection: CGFloat
            switch verticalAlignment {
            case .center:
                topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale) / 2.0
            case .bottom:
                topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale)
            case .top, .fill:
                topCorrection = 0
            @unknown default:
                topCorrection = 0
            }
            contentInset.top = max(0, topCorrection)
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems not to work with `isScrollEnabled` set to `false`.

Every other solution I found on the internet didn't work either and I'm a bit hopeless… Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you intended to use a UITextField?

```
let field = UITextField()
field.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
```

Or set it to .bottom, .top, etc.

Comment: Thanks! But a `UITextField` is one-line only…

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom textView

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var selectedTextRange: UITextRange? {
        get {
            return nil
        } set {

        }
    }

    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let tapGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer,
            tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 1 {
            return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
        }

        if let longPressGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer,

            longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration < 0.325 {
            return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
        }
        gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
        return false
    }
}
```

Use this textview as a baseclass for the textview

Comment: How is it supposed to answer my question?